# Correct way to solve limit with square root in denominator

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I would like to know how to correctly solve limit as $x$ approaches negative infinity for the following expression.

$$\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{4x^2-2}+1}$$

I would post my attempt at a solution but I apparently can not post pictures and I do not know how to use the mathematical notation very well. But I attempted to solve it like any "power type" limit, trying to dig out the $x$ from the numerator and denominator so it can cancels out. Doing that, I arrived at a result of $1$, but according to a smart book it should be $-1$.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: hint: $\sqrt{4x^2}=2|x|=-2x$ when $x<0$

Comment: @Vasya Of course I completely ignored that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Write the denominator as $$|x|\left(\sqrt{4-\frac{2}{x^2}}+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)$$ and the numerator as $$x\left(2+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ and note that $$\frac{x}{|x|}=-1$$ if $$x<0$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{2x+1}{\sqrt{4x^2-2}+1}=\dfrac{2x+1}{|x|\sqrt{4-2/x^2}+1}=\dfrac{2x+1}{-x\sqrt{4-2/x^2}+1}$$
$$=\dfrac{2+1/x}{-\sqrt{4-2/x^2}+1/x}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Divide numerator and denominator by $x$.$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac{2x+1}{\sqrt{4x^2-2}+1}=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\dfrac{2+1/x}{-\sqrt{4-2/x^2}+1/x}\to-1$$

---

**Aliter**:

Let $t=-x \iff t\to \infty$ as $x\to -\infty$. Therefore the limit translates to: $$\begin{aligned}\lim_{x\to -\infty}\dfrac{2x+1}{\sqrt{4x^2-2}+1}&=\lim_{t\to \infty}\dfrac{-2t+1}{\sqrt{4t^2-2}+1}\\&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{-2+1/t}{\sqrt{4-2/t^2}+1}\to -1\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Set $-\dfrac1x=y\iff x=-\dfrac1y\implies y\to0^+,y>0$

$$\sqrt{4x^2-2}=\sqrt{\dfrac{4-2y^2}{y^2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{4-2y^2}}y$$   as $\sqrt{y^2}=|y|$ which is $+y$ as $y\ge0$